# Windows Server 2012 after restart public network become private

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, windows-server-2012, nic

I have a 3 servers with Windows Server 2012.
After restart one server :
public network become private and private network become public. (2 NIC)

I don't know how this can happen and how to fix it ? I have tried to set Network Location Awareness to delayed automatic and restart all 3 machines without success.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the latest updates on the server. Under network and sharing, select your NIC, and then go to the advance sharing settings link. Reset the network back to the way you had it, and you shouldn't have to do it again.