# How do I make a connection private on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

After a restart of one of our servers (a Windows Server 2012 R2), all private connections become public and vice versa ([this user had the same problem](https://serverfault.com/q/533679/48320)). Stuff like pinging and iSCSI stopped working, and after some investigation it turned out this was the cause.

The problem is that I don't know how to make them private again. Left-clicking the network icon in the tray shows the "modern" sidebar, but it only shows a list of connections, and right-clicking them doesn't show any options.

What could be the problem, and is there a way to change these settings? I have to make one of the connections public (Internet access), and two of them private (backbone).

Comment: For anyone just needing to set a network from public to private (or vice versa), this works all the way up through Windows Server 2019 http://www.riptidehosting.com/blog/windows-server-how-to-change-public-network-to-private-network/ - It won't address your deeper issues though.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Powershell. Here is an example of changing the network profile of a network interface called Ethernet1 from whatever it is now to "Private." I got this info from `Get-Help Set-NetConnectionProfile -Full`.

```
PS C:\>$Profile = Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet1

PS C:\>$Profile.NetworkCategory = "Private"

PS C:\>Set-NetConnectionProfile -InputObject $Profile
```

Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/set-netconnectionprofile?view=winserver2012r2-ps

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me. One tiny correction ([the TechNet article for `Set-NetConnectionProfile` also has this typo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899565.aspx)): `Private` should be a string in the second line, i.e. `$Profile.NetworkCategory = "Private"` is correct. The same goes for the connection name (`"Ethernet1"`).

Comment: I have created a script that does this for all connection profiles including ones that aren't currently active yet: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/dbd2d94840cdaf79d3f6964bbd58e92f

Comment: Thanks for a proper solution that doesn't open up RDP on any unknown network.

Comment: techman's answer shows how to do the same thing with a more elegant one-liner: `Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet1 -NetworkCategory Private`

Comment: Works great at Windows Server 2016 Standard

Comment: works great at Windows Server 2019 Standard. BTW, the user interface doesn't do the trick even with the user in the administrator profile.

Answer (score 59):

A GUI way of making this change:

1. Hit **Winkey + R** to open Run prompt and type **gpedit.msc**
2. Navigate to: `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Setting /Network List Manager Policies`.
3. Choose your Network name in the right pane.
   **Note:** To show networks not currently connected, right-click **Network List Manager Policies** in the left pane and choose **Show All Networks**.
4. Go to Network Location tab and change the **Location type** from Public to Private.
   [image]
5. Close Local Policy Editor.

Source:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/82ccc68c-947e-435a-a237-1090f38d0dbe/windows-server-2012-r2-datacenter-network-stuck-in-public-mode

Comment: How do I set network as Domain Network?

Comment: You can't manually change a network to a domain network. Once you join the machine to a domain it will set the network as Domain Network.

Comment: Please note that if you set "user Permission: user CAN change location", the location type above is not applied. Set this to "cannot"

Answer (score 38):

Using Powershell. Here is an example of changing the network profile of a network interface called Ethernet to "Private." This is a one line command.

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -NetworkCategory Private
```

This will work on any local computer with Powershell installed.

Comment: This is basically what the accepted answer states, right?

Comment: This command does not require a variable.  One line and done.  It is an improved command.

Comment: Also,  The reason I discovered this command is because the accepted answer does not work for me. This command sets the connection type directly without discovery.

Comment: Why does it not work? I don't see much difference?

Comment: It does BTW not work on Windows 7, this comandlet is introduced in 2012/8.

Comment: I prefer the 'no-variables' way.

Comment: Use: `get-NetConnectionProfile` to check current status and names of your interfaces.

Comment: The `InterfaceAlias` may be quite long (e.g. `vEthernet (Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet - Virtual Switch)`).  So you may find it easier to refer to it with `-InterfaceIndex` instead, which will be a small integer.

Comment: This solution works, but is not permanent on my Server 2012 machines.  After reboot, the connections go back to being Public.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue for months on my home 2012R2 Domain Controller.

After patching and a reboot I could not connect via RDP.

I have MS firewall turned off in GPO for **domain** networks. After not being able to connect I found that the primary Ethernet connection was listed as **public** and therefore the firewall was ON.

Why is the NIC changing from domain to public ?
After researching a few articles on the web, I've concluded the following:

After a restart of the only DC in the domain, AD services are not immediately available when the IP stack is initialized.
This results in the OS sensing that this is a **public** network and it sets the NIC accordingly.

Permanent resolution of this problem on this machine was to set the Network Location Awareness service to **delayed start**.

This allows AD services to become available and then the OS senses a **domain** network and sets the NIC accordingly.

Comment: +1 for the delayed start advice.

Comment: Our go-to permanent fix is to set NlaSvc as a dependency of all the other network services. This prevents the possibility of any other service being inexplicably delayed, or crashing, and causing NlaSvc to fire too early.

`> sc config nlasvc depend=NSI/RpcSs/TcpIp/Dhcp/Eventlog/DNS/NTDS`

Answer (score 3):

Another simpler way with Powershell:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: This could set all NICs to private since no specific adapter is specified.

Comment: Short and sweet... All network profiles are all set to Private in one short command.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on a VM and just had to restart the Network Location Awareness service to get it to figure out that it was connected to a Domain and start using a domain profile.

Answer (score 0):

What made it work on my Windows Server 2012 R2 standard servers was to enable IPV6 again.

In a move to make future troubleshooting easier for myself I disabled IPV6 left right and center and after doing that the Windows Firewall no longer showed that 'Domain' was connected.

Why on earth Windows can't determine that it's on a domain if only IPV4 is connected is beyond me.

bah