# How to change NIC Location in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have a windows server 2012 R2 machine that is acting as a domain controller and I have a virtual network interface(VMNET3) that is automatically placed in the domain profile.

Is there any way to change it to the private profile?

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/questions/639088/how-do-i-make-a-connection-private-on-windows-server-2012-r2/639090#639090