# Teamviewer 13 in windows server 2012 R2 breaks RDP and file sharing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdesktop

Few days ago i upgraded tv to v13, then yesterday i assign the machine to my email.

But it seemed to break few things

1. File sharing broke, luckily i was able to fix it with making a new file share,  windows then prompt me to "allow file and printer share?" or something like that. Which is strange because my server is primarily used for data sharing on a local client.
2. Rdesktop broke, i still havent found the cause of this and i cant fix it yet.
   things ive tried :

   - GUI settings is already enabled,
   - firewall off,
   - av nod32 off,
   - registry for rdesktop is already correct
   - restart "server" service
     yet none of those fix it.
     I'm sure this is caused by tv cause i didn't make any other changes that day,

any idea what went wrong with my rdesktop?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Apparently TV disables public network for rdesktop, travisIT's answer here solved it
[Server 2012 - Remote Desktop Stopped Working | Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1786574-server-2012-remote-desktop-stopped-working)

Comment: Just want to add, apparently after enabling file sharing on a folder, win server 2012 r2 pops up a message to change connection to public, i think this is what screwed up my rdesktop, this answer fixed it https://serverfault.com/a/704295/254840