# SQL2016 ODBC login fail on first attempt

Tags: networking, sql-server

My current SQL server version is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)
>       Mar 18 2018 09:11:49
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: )

I am connecting to SQL through MS Access MDB using ODBC.
Yesterday this worked fine, today not - difference I believe is Server windows update.

Today when Access attempts connection, I get the following error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Login
>   Connection failed: SQL state: S1T00
>   SQL server error 0
>   Microsoft ODBC SQL server driver login timeout expired

After Clicking "OK", things connect, and everything works without issue

It is not a DNS issue - using the IP address rather than server name does not resolve. The connection to SQL in SSMS works without issue.  I have tried MS SQL sever ODBC driver 13 and 17.

I think it has something to do with the windows/SQL update, because this happened 20 days ago, and after trying many things, I "repaired" SQL Server and the issue went away.  Instead of a SQL repair again, I need to find the true cause - any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Issue was not because of SQL version.

Issue stemmed from firewall and network interface.

If I turned the windows public firewall OFF, things worked (ON not work).

When I force the server connection to=Private - things work (with firewall ON).

Previously Location Type=Not configured

Stack Exchange with detail on this:

[How do I make a connection private on Windows Server 2012 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/639088/how-do-i-make-a-connection-private-on-windows-server-2012-r2)